# Copy from recordset with VBScript

Tags: excel, vba, csv, vbscript

I pull data from an Oracle database using VBscript and place the recordset result into a csv file. Here is my code,

```
Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Set ssfile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile("C:\Users\jasons\Documents\Closing_stock\scripts\SuperSession.csv")

con.Open "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=athena)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=jasdnf)));User Id=xxxx;Password=xxxx"
rs.Open "select * from mytable", con, 1, 3

ssfile.WriteLine "ITEM, ALTITEM"
rs.MoveFirst
Do
ssfile.WriteLine rs("item") & "," & rs("altitem")
rs.MoveNext
Loop Until rs.EOF

rs.Close
con.Close
Set con = Nothing
```

The code works fine. The problem I have is that there is about 4 million records and it takes the code long to loop through each record and paste it into the csv file. Is there a similar function in VBscript as in Excel-VBA such as CopyFromRecordset, where the whole recordset can be dumped into a sheet. So I would like to dump the recordset result into the csv file without having to loop through each record. How can I do this?

Comment: Being 4 million records probably you will need to repeat the process for smaller blocks, but you can try with the recordset's [GetString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676975%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [`GetString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676975%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which returns all (or optionally, a subset) of your recordset as a string where you can specify the delimiters etc:

```vb
Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Set ssfile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile("C:\Users\jasons\Documents\Closing_stock\scripts\SuperSession.csv")

con.Open "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=athena)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=jasdnf)));User Id=xxxx;Password=xxxx"
rs.Open "select * from mytable", con, 1, 3

ssfile.WriteLine "ITEM, ALTITEM"
rs.MoveFirst

ssfile.writeline rs.GetString(2, , ",")

rs.Close
con.Close
Set con = Nothing
```

Not sure if you need to supply a rowdelimiter or not, you may need to experiment - eg try `rs.GetString(2, , ",", vbNewLine)`